# Parsing strings into values with incremental key dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, dictionary

I would like to parse the string into dictionary char by char with key being incremental value 1..n depending on the length of string and value being D or U character, throwing `"_"` char away in the process. Something like this:

"D_U_U_U_U_D_D_D_D_D_D_U_D_D_U_U_D_U_U_D_D_U_D_D" string into a dict such as this one `d = {'1':'D','2':'U','3':'U','4':'U','5':'U','6':'D' ... etc}`.

I have been able to split the `"_"` char but I was unsuccessful with generating the incremental key 1 ..n value.

Thanks for help.

Comment: "unsuccessful" how? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what code you tried, and what it produced (to contrast with what you wanted). Asking us to write it for your from scratch is not appropriate.

Comment: A dict with incremental continuous integer keys is no better than a list.

Comment: If you don't care if the key is an int then `dict(enumerate(s[::2]))` would work.

Comment: @AChampion: That assumes that the underscores are guaranteed to occur at odd indices. `dict(enumerate(s.replace('_', ''), 1))` would obey the requirement (skip underscores) rather than assuming "skip odds" is equivalent.

Comment: @ShadowRanger true, though the example was alternating, so perhaps a valid constraint. `replace()` is definitely more general.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary comprehension will do the trick:

```
s = "D_U_U_U_U_D_D_D_D_D_D_U_D_D_U_U_D_U_U_D_D_U_D_D"
d = {str(position):letter for position, letter in enumerate(s.replace('_', ''), 1)}
print(d)
```

#### Output

```
{'1': 'D', '2': 'U', '3': 'U', '4': 'U', '5': 'U', '6': 'D', '7': 'D', '8': 'D', '9': 'D', '10': 'D', '11': 'D', '12': 'U', '13': 'D', '14': 'D', '15': 'U', '16': 'U', '17': 'D', '18': 'U', '19': 'U', '20': 'D', '21': 'D', '22': 'U', '23': 'D', '24': 'D'}
```

Or heck, if you don't want others to understand what's going on:

```
import itertools
d = dict(zip(map(str, itertools.count(1)), filter('_'.__ne__, s)))
```

The obfuscated version does take less memory for long `s`.

Comment: OP had string keys not int keys.  Also they started at 1, not 0.

Comment: I like `dict(enumerate(s.split('_'), 1))` better.

Comment: Given it's character based, not "runs of non-underscores" based, you'd want `enumerate(s.replace('_', ''), 1)`. It'll be more efficient to boot.

Comment: @wim: Since the OP wants `str` keys (for whatever reason), using the `dict` constructor directly won't work, sadly. You'd have to get creative to the point where the `dict` comprehension would probably be the better option, something like `dict(zip(map(str, itertools.count(1)), s.replace('_', '')))` is not an improvement on `{str(pos): let for pos, let in enumerate(s.replace('_', ''), 1)}` IMO, even if it's slightly more concise and (probably) slightly faster.

Comment: Any reason not to use `s[::2]`?

Comment: I'm totally in favor of `dict(zip(map(str, itertools.count(1)), s.replace('_', '')))` and deploying it to production without documentation. or in case op is using python2, `dict(itertools.izip(itertools.imap(str, itertools.count(1)), s.replace('_', '')))`

Comment: @SebastianWozny: The aggressively awful `filter('_'.__ne__, s)` is a nice addition. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I thought you would like it.

Comment: Thank you all for all answers, @wim thanks, works like a charm and is compact (I must look into enumerate)